# Закрепление левого меню

Tags: меню, html, css

Доброе время суток. Как можно реализовать стрницу сайта с закрепленным левым меню? 
Пример:

[image]

Так же интересует само разделение (как на `frame` например), но `frame` использовать не надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="float:left">
левое меню
</div>
<div style="float:right">
страница с информацией
</div>
```

Если нужно добавить полосы прокрутки, то добавляем в свойства высоту height: 600px и overflow:auto